# struct vs class performance test

Tags: c#, performance, class, struct

I built a test and got following results:

> allocating classes: 15.3260622, allocating structs: 14.7216018.

Looks like a 4% advantage when allocates structs instead of classes. That's cool but is it really enough to add in the language value types? Where I can find an example which shows that structs really beat classes?

```
void Main()
{
    var stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    stopWatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        var foo = new refFoo()
        {
            Str = "Alex" + i
        };
    }

    stopWatch.Stop();

    stopWatch.Dump();

    stopWatch.Restart();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        var foo = new valFoo()
        {
            Str = "Alex" + i
        };
    }

    stopWatch.Stop();

    stopWatch.Dump();


}

public struct valFoo
{
    public string Str;
}

public class refFoo
{
    public string Str;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the 100000000 string concatenations you're performing in both of your tests. Those are almost certainly the overwhelming factor in your code.

Comment: Just tried this myself, and on my machine, about 95% of the time of your benchmark is taken with string concatenation. Just comment out the `Str = ` lines in each case (or change the value to a constant). Not that I'd recommend having public fields or mutable structs anyway.

Comment: It's not only about allocation. How about garbage collection?

Comment: @Jon Skeet my bad, without concatenation the difference about 3 times. It is really good.

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova Probably it also improves performance but I'm trying to find real examples and how much is the difference between struct and classes. Almost everywhere I read that it is faster, but I don't understand how is fast structs.

Comment: You should be using a value type when your type logically represents a value, and a class when it doesn't.

Comment: @Servy sure, but if I want to improve performance of my application I would like to go a little deeper than this postulate.

Comment: @Neir0 Making a type that's not logically a representation of a value a value type is likely to make programming with that type a nightmare, and is going to require an in-depth understanding of value/reference semantics in C#.  It's very rarely the right call.

Comment: @Neir0 - GC differences partially come from the fact you need less traversal for true structs (something like `Vector3d`) - GC can handle whole array or million of items in single check vs. walking and marking each of reference to an object... But you may get similar benefits with immutable objects. As Servy pointed out structs have very surprising semantic especially if you are not from C/C++ background or not used to immutable objects/functional programming anyway.

Comment: Running a single test, especially if the numbers are close, is not a good methodology. You need the standard deviation before you can calculate how sure you are that the first method performs better than the second. Also swapping the sequence in which the tests are done can have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 7):

Your methodology is wrong. You are mostly measuring string allocations, conversions of integers to strings, and concatenation of strings.  This benchmark is not worth the bits it is written on.

In order to see the benefit of structs, compare allocating an array of 1000 objects and an array of 1000 structs.  In the case of the array of objects, you will need one allocation for the array itself, and then one allocation for each object in the array.  In the case of the array of structs, you have one allocation for the array of structs.

Also, look at the implementation of the Enumerator of the List class in the C# source code of .Net collections.  It is declared as a struct. That's because it only contains an int, so the entire enumerator struct fits inside a machine word, so it is very inexpensive.

Comment: That plus even if he did what you suggested he would still only check allocation performance, which is a tiny aspect of performance vs actually using the types.

Answer (score -4):

Try some simpler test:

```
int size = 1000000;
var listA = new List<int>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    listA.Add(i);

var listB = new List<object>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    listB.Add(i);
```

To store 1000000 integers in first case the system allocates 4000000 bytes. In second, if I'm not mistaken — about 12000000 bytes. And I suspect the performance difference will be much greater.

Comment: You're not comparing struct vs class here but struct vs boxing a struct

Comment: Hmm, actually, @RonanThibaudau has a point. (Initially I misunderstood what he was saying.)

Comment: @MikeNakis Generics *allow* the `List` to avoid boxing when storing values *by specifying the value type as the generic argument*.  When you don't do that, and have `object` as the type of the `List`, then the value types need to be boxed when placed within it.

Comment: @Servy yes, that is correct. Initially I thought that Ronan was talking about something else.  So, I removed my earlier comment.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau The single reason of boxing's existence is a structs. If there were no structs, why do we need a boxing?

Comment: Mark, boxing is generally considered to be an unfortunate but necessary drawback of value types, so, when the goal is to demonstrate how `struct` can perform better than `class` it is best to avoid using boxing in any way, shape or form in your example code.

Comment: @MikeNakis, try to look it another way: boxing shows explicit price we pay when we create a class instead of a struct. There are two prices: memory penalty (as I remember, 8/16 bytes in 32/64-bit machines), and performance penalty, cause we are forced to call a constructor, even if it does nothing. So I think my example shows the measure of overhead accurately. You can, of course, compare *int* and *class containing a single int field* explicitly. But it's doubtful whether results will differ significantly.

Comment: Mark, I know that what you are saying is technically correct, (and that's why I did not downvote.) but still it is bad as an example, because it does not keep the two concepts that are being compared entirely separate from each other, so there is a possibility that things may be happening under the hood that are not obvious, or at least that's what any skeptic is allowed to suspect.

Comment: The magician allows the audience to examine the hat to be sure it is empty before he pulls a rabbit out of it.  The magician does not say "l know, there is a black rabbit already in there, but please ignore it, it does not matter, because the rabbit that I am going to pull out will be white" even though pulling a white rabbit out of a hat that contained a black rabbit is just as miraculous as pulling a white rabbit out of an empty hat.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko you're thinking backward, yes boxing is a side effect of casting structs into higher types but that has nothing to do with his question which was about struct vs class speed (and not about boxing them). When you use structs you usually do not box them nor need to do so so the answer was completely off topic.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko and no boxing doesn't "show the price of classes" at all, there's no boxing involved when working with a class, it's a totally diferent price. Your measurement has nothing to do with the performance profile (both memory and speed) of structs and classes but only with "classes vs boxing structs". It's completely irrelevant